# Kubernetes Load Balancing with Redis Cluster and microservices

Tags: kubernetes, redis, architecture, microservices, load-balancing

I have the following scenario:

- N kubernetes Nodes
- A redis cluster with N instances, each node has a single instance
- There are requests coming into the nodes in a round-robin format
- After the requests, my data is processed by microservices that are communicating through Redis lists that are named the following way: <SERVICE_PREFIX>:{CLUSTER_HASH_SLOT}

On the the Nodes I have a network packet rate limit that I would like to solve with this approach, because we are constantly on the edge of hitting it. (Mostly because of the node-to-node communications)

Assumption: After the request comes in and is pushed to the correct Redis instance, it will not leave the node, since we will always use the same hash slot, and therefore the same Redis instance.

If this is the case then this will solve my problem, because if i get closer to the limit I can just boot up additional nodes, with the same configuration.

**Is my assumption correct? Could this work?**

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: @me_the_bo can you clarify, what is your question?

Comment: @Jonas thanks, I'm interested in any feedback on whether this could work or anything that I need to pay attention to.

Comment: @me_the_bo if it "could work" is a very broad question, you need to focus the question on a specific problem you have.